# Daily SQL report to identify changes

Tags: sql, excel, salesforce

Looking for any advice, I am currently running a SQL Server system. I want to run a query on a daily basis, export the returned data and compare it the previous days exports.

The reason I'm doing this is to identify any changes over a 24 hour period within the data. I have SalesForce available to me, if that's not practical I was just going to use Excel, although this feels clunky and I'm working with 96000~ rows.

Any thoughts would be great

Comment: do your tables have last updated timestamps on them? do your tables have a unique primary key?

Comment: No, there is no timestamp currently and I don't have the ability to modify the table myself.  They do have a numerical PK

Answer (score 0):

if you can, add an audit table and 2 trigger that inserts on updates or deletions
its easy then to compare

```
create table tbl1(Pkey uniqueidentifier, col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100))--your initial table
create table tbl1_audit(Pkey uniqueidentifier, col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), modified_on datetime)--audit table
create trigger tbl_update
on tbl1 after update 
as
insert into tbl_audit
select *,getdate() from inserted
```

its only a matter of joining the tables and comparing after that.
you can scrub it whenever you want, but there aren't any other practical means of accessing the original data and the changed data of which im aware.

Comment: This is great, Thank You!